# Vue: How do I generate a new instance of a div with a buttonclick?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to create a function that generates a new instance of a specific div (.container in the template) when a button (#addDiv) is clicked. The button should be the only thing visible on the webpage before that. How do I do?

I know that it may be possible to do this with document.appendChild. Is there a better way?

I am using toggle-function that works great, I have included it in the code to give you the whole picture.

**Vue**

```
    Vue.component('dynamicdDvs', {
    template: `

<div>
    <div class="headerDiv">
        <button class="addDiv" type="button" v-on:click="createDiv">Create</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="createdDiv">
            <h2>I am dynamic!</h2>
            <button class="minimize" v-on:click="expand">Make me smal</button>
        </div>
        <div class="createdDivMinimized" v-if="!displayDiv">
            <p>I am a smal version of the created div!</p>
            <button class="maximize" v-on:click="expand">Expand me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`,

  data:function () {
    return {
        displayDiv: false

    }
  },
  methods:  {
        expand: function () {
            this.displayDiv = !this.displayDiv;
        },

        createDiv: function() {
          //The function that creates a new div, with the same code as 
          //.createdDiv and .createDivMinimized may be placed here
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.headerDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white
}

.createdDiv {
  height: 300px;
   width: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white
}

.createdDivMinimized {
  height: 300px;
   width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="parent">

<dynamicDivs></dynamicDivs>

</div>
```

Comment: you can add the div to your template normally and show/hide by if statement, the if statement is add/remove the entire element from the DOM

for instance.
@onClick="showDiv = !showDiv"

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is set a number in `data` for the number of `<div>` elements and use [`v-for` with a range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range). For example

```
data () {
  return {
    displayDiv: [false],
    divs: 1
  }
}
```

And in your template

```
<template v-for="n in divs">
  <div class="createdDiv">
    <!-- snip -->
    <button class="minimize" v-on:click="displayDiv[n-1] = !displayDiv[n-1]">Make me small</button>
  </div>
  <div class="createdDivMinimized" v-if="!displayDiv[n-1]">
    <!-- snip -->
  </div>
</template>
```

and in your methods...

```
createDiv () {
  this.divs++
  this.displayDiv.push(false)
}
```

Comment: This wasn't the solution to my problem but after 3 days of searching this was an inspiration that made my code finally work!